# Trouble having mongodb code to php having $and $not and mongoregex operator

Tags: php, mongodb

i am having difficulty to convert mongodb shell command to php.
In shell i am using

```
db.files.find({"username":"username",
$and:[
{'filetype': {$not : /image/}},
{'filetype':{$not:/application/}},
{'filetype':{$not:/video/}}
]

})
```

As you can see i am having diffculty to convert it to php. I tried few way on stack overflow but got empty result. Can anyone help on this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
$db->files->find(array(
  'username' => 'username',
  '$and' => array(
    array('filetype' => array('$not' => new MongoRegex('/image/'))),
    array('filetype' => array('$not' => new MongoRegex('/application/'))),
    array('filetype' => array('$not' => new MongoRegex('/video/'))),
  ),
));
```

BTW you could use this tiny script, to convert JSON representations to PHP:

```
var_export(json_decode($jsonAsString, true));
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer. Btw how 
var_export(json_decode($jsonAsString, true));
How this helps to convert most of mongoshell command to php.

Comment: If you have your *where* in json (f.ex. `'{"username":"username"}'`) this script would show to you how it would be in php: `var_export(json_decode('{"username":"username"}', true))` => `array('username' => 'username')`